# Failed to parse query using Elastic Search API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using POST /_search API to search data in elastic search 5.6.0.

When I tried to search for query **Android 8.0 (Oreo)** search API worked successfully, but when I tried for **Android 8.0 (Oreo** elastic search failed with error **Failed to parse query [Android 8.0 (Oreo]** 
Please have a look at error below:

```
{
  "shard":0,
  "index":"my_index",
  "node":"-Dzw5527SZGf7U0Ebut0PQ",
  "reason":{
    "type":"query_shard_exception",
    "reason":"Failed to parse query [Android 8.0 (Oreo]",
    "index_uuid":"wo7ihAX8Syy15MSDrS-Wsw",
    "index":"my_index",
    "caused_by":{
      "type":"parse_exception",
      "reason":"Cannot parse 'Android 8.0 (Oreo': Encountered \"<EOF>\" at line 1, column 17.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <AND> ...\r\n    <OR> ...\r\n    <NOT> ...\r\n    \"+\" ...\r\n    \"-\" ...\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \")\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    \"^\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ",
      "caused_by":{
        "type":"parse_exception",
        "reason":"Encountered \"<EOF>\" at line 1, column 17.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <AND> ...\r\n    <OR> ...\r\n    <NOT> ...\r\n    \"+\" ...\r\n    \"-\" ...\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \")\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    \"^\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below query worked for me :

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "query_string":{
            "query":"Android 8.0 (Oreo)",
            "default_operator":"AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Below query throws an exception:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "query_string":{
            "query":"Android 8.0 (Oreo",
            "default_operator":"AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

could you please help me on this, why am I getting an error when I missed **)** in a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parenthesis is a [reserved character](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) in the [query string syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax), so you need to escape it like this

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "query_string":{
            "query":"Android 8.0 \\(Oreo",
            "default_operator":"AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val, I tried this as well. If I try to escape it using \, it throws me an error  {
                "type": "json_parse_exception",
                "reason": "Unrecognized character escape '(' (code 40)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@59ed12ad; line: 7, column: 36]"
            }

Also, I would like to know, how come ( ) worked and ( not ?

Comment: My bad try again, you need to escape the backslash, too.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how come ( ) worked for me even without escaping

Comment: () worked but not as you expected, the parenthesis where simply wrapping the `Oreo` token but in no case they were matched

Comment: Thanks a lot, Val.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164189/discussion-between-pkhode-and-val).

Comment: Anything more needed to close this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.
String i was passing in the Postman was in wrong format.
please check the format.